# How do fix "Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close() may be required for workbook."

Tags: pandas, exception, pandas.excelwriter

I want to export values from a dataframe in python to excel.

If I don't add'writer.save()' at the end :I get the following Exception: Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close() may be required for workbook.
I have not created a separate workbook.
On adding 'writer.save()', I am getting PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'F:........\docs.xlsx'

I tried executing my program with and without adding writer.save(), still I get an Exception or PermissionError

```py
# file_compare is a function comparing 2 excel files
# newpath is the path for storing newly created excel file

new_df= file_compare(df1, df2)
_logger.info('Creating new excel file')
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(newpath, engine='xlsxwriter')
new_df.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=True)
writer.save()
_logger.info('File successfully created.')
```

I want that the file should get saved in newfile location.

Comment: *I am getting PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied*. Your issue is either that the file is already open in Excel, and hence you cannot overwrite it; you don't have permission to write to the target folder; or possibly the name/path to the folder is wrong. Try debug it in that order.

Comment: Yes @jmcnamara, Excel file was open. Now the code is working fine.